# Angular run jQuery code for all site

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I want to implement http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ in my project (AngularJS based project).

What I need to do is:

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

However, where do I place this if I need it to run throughout the site and as soon as the DOM finishes loading? Not sure if a directive is what I need, and if so, how would it be and where should I include/run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use jquery plugins in angular projects are the use of directives.

HTML:

```
…
<body ng-app="myApp" nicescroll>

</body>
…
```

JS:

```
…
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('nicescroll', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function() {
            // check, if the jquery plugin is loaded and available
            if ($.fn.niceScroll) {
                $('html').niceScroll();
            }
        }
    }
});
…
```

Comment: it's better to check `$.fn.niceScroll`

Comment: Solved. Great, I thought of making an controller and putting it in the body and doing the above, but this works and it's cleaner.